# NodeJS Heroku app failing with Error R10 (Boot timeout)

Tags: node.js, heroku

Heroku detects my app as a NodeJS app because I have a package.json

It runs the start script:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "npm run build && live-server --no-browser build",
```

The build starts, but in the middle of the build I get this error:

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

The build script removes the build directory then starts building and creates a new build directory

The live-server is a web server dependency that responds to the PORT env variable.

I can successfully run locally with this command:

```
$ PORT=8000 heroku local
```

Building on my local system takes 35 seconds but it's a very fast laptop.

Comment: The solution was to move the build step to postinstall